# Using str_replace in preg_match_all result

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
preg_match_all('#href="/mp3/(.*?).html#', $content, $salida);
```

and I need to replace "_" to " " (space) in output (array), something like this

```
$salida = str_replace('_', ' ', $salida);
```

obviously that code does not work

Comment: `$salida` is an array. [RTM](http://php.net/preg-match-all)

Comment: So, how can I do it ?

Comment: "But not works"? In what way does it not work? Can we see an example of the source string, and the resulting output and desired output?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback)

```
$salida = preg_replace_callback(
    '(href="/mp3/.*?\.html)',
    function($m) {return str_replace("_","",$m[0]);},
    $content);
```

Comment: no, this is not for _all. Also you use the function wrong. Most upvoters seem to be blinded by your creative way of formatting the code, so they do not seem to notice :D